# Expo Go app crashes when long pressing with react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native, expo

Crash only occurs when using router.push; doesn't happen when replaced with console.log().

```
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { router } from 'expo-router';

// ...

const longPressGesture = Gesture.LongPress().onEnd((_e, success) => {
  if (success) {
    router.push('/products/edit'); // Crashes here
  }
});

// ...

<GestureDetector gesture={longPressGesture}>
  <ScrollView>
    {products.map((product, index) => (
      <Card key={index} />
    ))}
  </ScrollView>
</GestureDetector>
```

`react-native-gesture-handler` version used is `2.14.0`
and `expo` version is `50.0.5`

I have wrapped the root layout with `GestureHandlerRootView` and using Expo Go simulator for testing.